# How to delete substring from a string recursively without using recursion?

Tags: string, algorithm

Example:
Delete "816" **recursively** from string  "8816168168".
Result will be "8";

Is there any other way to realize this function **without using recursion?**

Recursion may like:

```
function deleteSubstring($string){
    //...
    return deleteSubstring($subString);
}
```

I don't need this solution. Is there any other one?
You can using any language or pseudocode.

Comment: *"recursively without using recursion"* - ? - You mean using a loop?

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by "delete substring from a string recursively", the "example" that you bring does not help at all to shed light on this, and the code that you show does not make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution using a `while` loop:

```js
function deleteSubstring(str1, str2){

   while(str1.indexOf(str2) > -1)
      str1 = str1.replace(str2, '');
      
   return str1;
}

console.log(deleteSubstring('8816168168','816'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a for loop.

```
function deleteSubstring($string){
  while($substring.isEmpty()){
      ...... ...
         code for the deleting the substring
      ......... 

  }
  return $string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the conundrum. I thought initially that a simple `.replace` with regxexp would solve it ...

```
str.replace(/(816)/g, '')
```

... but that one returns `8168`.

So I would still need to loop this through:

```
function cleanString(str, removeStr) {
  while (str.indexOf(removeStr) != -1) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(removeStr, 'g'), '');
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: Instead of regular expresion we can use repalceAll function i.e str.replaceAll('816'). This function is available in java language